# Complex SQL Query - nested query

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

Here is the job_form table...

```
job_num  | name | address |
---------+------+---------+
 1       | Tom  | Smith   |
 2       | John | Doe     |
 3       | Max  | Smith   |
```

Here is the individual_job table...

```
job_num  | date       | description   |
---------+------+---------------------+
 1       | 23-01-2012 | Eat food      |
 1       | 24-01-2012 | Do dishes     |
 1       | 25-01-2012 | Sweep floor   |
 ...     | ...        | ...           |
 2       | 19-05-2013 | Play games    |
 2       | 23-05-2013 | Do code       |
 2       | 27-05-2013 | Sleep         |
 ...     | ...        | ...           |
 3       | 23-05-2013 | Eat food      |
 3       | 24-05-2013 | Do dishes     |
 3       | 25-05-2013 | Sweep floor   |
 ...     | ...        | ...           |
```

I would like to create a query that pulls out a single row for each job_form which includes the date of the first job to be completed, the date of the last job to be completed as well as the total number of jobs listed on the form. The query needs to display only job forms which have jobs which need to be completed in the future.

Example is:

```
job_num  |  first_job_date  |  last_job_date  |  count_of_jobs  |  name
---------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------
2        |  19-05-2013      |  27-05-2013     |  3              |  John
3        |  23-05-2013      |  25-05-2013     |  3              |  Max
```

I haven't done SQL for a few years, and this one has me completely stumped. I know I have to do a nested query, but can't work out the order...

Any help much appreciated.

Updated to include name column in result (forgot about this, sorry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** As per Gordon, there is no need for a join if you don't require any of the `job_form` specific fields. However, if you do (e.g. name or address), then:

```
SELECT jf.job_id,
       jf.name, 
       MIN(ij.date) AS first_job_date, 
       MAX(ij.date) as last_job_date, 
       COUNT(*) as count_of_jobs
FROM job_form jf
  INNER JOIN individual_job ij
    ON jf.job_num = ij.job_num
GROUP BY jf.job_id, jf.name -- i.e. non-aggregated select fields here
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple aggregation query:

```
select ij.job_num,
       min(ij.date) as first_job_date,
       max(ij.date) as last_job_date, count(*) as count_of_jobs
from individual_job ij
group by ij.job_num
```

For future jobs, you need a date comparison, something like the following (depending on the database):

```
where date >= sysdate
```

or

```
where date >= now()
```

or

```
where date >= getdate()
```

The `where` clause goes after the `from` clause.